# Line Termination

Tags: power-supply, power, mains

In the 3- Phase AC Transmission of Power,If the line is terminated through a resistor having a value equal to the characteristic impedance of the line,isn't large chunks of power gets wasted?

Comment: Yes it will be.

Answer (score 2):

Who told you that powerline is terminated by a characteristics impedance resistor? Also the powerline forms a net, many of them like spider net. There is not a single powerline terminated at both ends, reflections are tolerated because the frequency is very low and SWR ratio is good. 
The phenomena is seen at long distance powerline, that's why it is rectified to DC and inverted back to AC at the end.

Comment: This was probably an exam/quiz type of question to test understanding in a contrived scenario.